# How to name regexp groups?

Tags: php, regex

I have a Regular Expression:

```
'/ abc \( (complexRegex)(,complexRegex)*? \) /Uux'
```

To match something like: abc(complexStructure,complexStructure,complexStructure)

How to not write complexRegex twice?

Answer (score 2):

In basic PHP, no way (except by using the variable trick as eisberg suggests, but it's still repeated in the regexp itself). In PHP5, I heard they put in Oniguruma (Ruby 1.9's extended regexp engine), but I haven't tried for myself, and can't find a decent reference except what Oniguruma's Wikipedia page says. If it's true, you can have [this](http://rubular.com/r/ZLNpjcc1g4):

```
/abc:(?<complexRegex>d.f)(,\g<complexRegex>)*:ghi/
```

It will match `"abc:def,daf,dif:ghi"`, for example, without repeating the pattern (`d.f`), by assigning a name to the pattern (`complexRegex`).

Comment: PHP still uses the PCRE library, but PCRE has adopted the "named" subroutine syntax (`\g<regex>`) for compatibility with Oniguruma. (ref: http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt and search for `ONIGURUMA SUBROUTINE SYNTAX`)

Comment: @AlanMoore: I was going by Wikipedia's "The Ruby programming language, since version 1.9, as well as PHP's multi-byte string module (since PHP5), use Oniguruma as their regular expression engine", and the linked Japanese source linked there saying how Oniguruma is bundled since PHP RC1 for use with `mbstring`; `mb_ereg` is supposed to be one of the functions that uses it. Still haven't tried for myself :) `preg_match` and friends are obviously PCRE (hence "p" prefix). I didn't know though that PCRE adopted those features; thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are in PHP you can avoid writing your complexRegex by variables!

```
$complexRegex = 'your complexRegex here';

$regex = '/ abc \( (' . $complexRegex . ')(,' . $complexRegex . ')*? \) /Uux';
```

Also read about back references in PCRE: http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php

Comment: Also have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php it is what you are looking for.

Comment: @eisberg: same comment as to garyh... The variable trick is good, but back-references here are probably too limited for the scenario here.

Comment: @Amadan Thank you for your comment. I have never seen a working example with back references in any project. So I did not want to include an example but nevertheless mention it.

Comment: This wont do the trick if I will want to name some groups in $complexRegexp: Warning Compilation failed: two named subpatterns have the same name at offset

Answer (score 0):

You can match 0 or 1 comma with ?

```
'/ abc \((,?(complexRegex))* \)/
```

I added white space to make it clearer but you should match any number of white spaces wherever required.

Comment: this will match: abc(complexStructurecomplexStructure)

Comment: That is not equivalent, since it will also match `",complexStructurecomplexStructure"` - even if it was syntactically well-formed

Answer (score -1):

You can also use [backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) eg

```
(x[ms]l).com/\1    

# the \1 is the backreference which matches the first capture group
```

will match

```
xml.com/xml
 and 
xsl.com/xsl
```

Comment: You can only use backreferences for literally same string regions; I suspect the OP wants their `complexRegex` to be somewhat more flexible (and potentially different in each instance).

Comment: @Amadan You may have a point there. Still, it got me reading up on backreferences and I now know more than I did an hour ago.